# Chrome issue with saved passwords - continuous form submit retries

Tags: html, forms, google-chrome, primefaces

I have web application (JSF - PrimeFaces) that started to have an issue on Google Chrome update 59. On 58 it was fine, and on every other browser it is fine.

What is happening is that when user logs in for the first time, if the user accepts that Chrome save the password, once the user logs out or once the user comes back to this page anytime, Chrome automatically tries to submit the login form with empty password and, upon failure, keeps trying forever.

Am I'm doing something wrong on my form?

I have created a sample app to demonstrate the problem:

https://powerful-badlands-23851.herokuapp.com/test

Steps to reproduce:

1. using chrome 59, login with "test@test.com" password "test"
2. When Chrome asks if you want to save the password say YES
3. now click logout... and you will should see the bug

Thanks

Comment: We faced the same problem today with JSF and Chrome 59. You found any solution ?

Comment: @csarathe no solution so far. I need to make a POST and I can't find an alternative. Please vote this question up and also vote [this question](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/n8TmpfHkdMI;context-place=forum/chrome) up on their forum.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is mainly caused by a bug on Primefaces with the p:defaultCommand as explained here: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/2448

Comment: @csarathe FYI this is a [bug](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/2448) in primefaces with the `p:defaultCommand` component. For now you could use [this](https://blog.sixthpoint.com/alternative-pdefaultcommand/) workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was actually a [bug](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/2448) in PrimeFaces 6 with `p:defaultCommand`. 
Since I could not upgrade it, I ended up using [this](https://blog.sixthpoint.com/alternative-pdefaultcommand/) workaround:

```
$('a.submitSearchButton').click();
return false;
}"/>
```

Comment: Thanks, upvoted! It's actually a bug in PrimeFaces 5, fixed in version 6.